# GCP list everything in a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Google Cloud Platform has a vast array of products. In a given project I might make use of Compute Engine, Cloud SQL, Kubernetes, Storage, IAM & Admin. Or I might make use of Cloud Run, VMware Engine, App Engine, Cloud Functions, and Spanner.

I don't know what the vast majority of these things do, and as I explore and learn it's hard to keep track of which products I use on a given project. But let's say I wanted to retrospectively document all the components of a project so that it could be recreated from scratch.

Short of going through every product one-by-one and looking for signs of past civilizations, is there some way to list all my footprints?

I think my goal can be pretty well summarized by the following pseudocode:

```
create project "blank-project"
diff "my-project" "blank-project"
```

Comment: Google Cloud does not have a single feature to accomplish exactly what you want. The closest is Cloud Assent Inventory: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview

Answer (score 0):

As John said, Cloud Asset inventory can help you for this. I recommend you to [export the assets to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-bigquery).

Why? Because like this you can easily perform a diff with a simple SQL query. You have 1 export per day and like this you can have an history of all your footprint.

However, it lists the assets, not the configuration of the assets. I mean, you know that you have a GKE cluster, but the content of the cluster (the services/pods that you have deployed on it) aren't listed. You make a diff of the component, not the content of the component.

A last tricky thing. Export to BigQuery is not really user friendly. here what I did inmy company to achieve this

- Create a cloud function that call the Cloud Asset inventory export in Python
- Create a Cloud Scheduler that trigger this function every day

The problem here is: every export the previous data are deleted and replace by the new ones. So, you have to do this

- Create a new BigQuery table, partitioned per day and with the same schema as the Asset tables
- Create a scheduled query (set the scheduler 15 minutes after the trigger of the Cloud Function) that copy the content of the asset export to the new partitioned table